# Understanding React-hook-form Controller

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am working on a website that has been build before me and it uses a method of the Controller part of react-hook-form that I have not seen before.

This is an example of the code:

```
const CheckboxController = (props: CheckboxProps) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Controller as={CheckboxInput} {...props} /> 
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

With `CheckboxInput` being a simple material-ui checkbox.

I understand the traditional method of using something like:

```
const CheckboxController = (props: CheckboxProps) => {
  return(
    <Controller
    name={props.name}
    control={props.control}
    render={({ field }) => (
      <label>
          <Checkbox
            onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e.target.checked)}
            checked={props.checked}
            disabled={props.isDisabled}
            />
            {props.label}
        </label>
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

But unfortunately the entire site is build upon the `<Controller as={}>` setup. I cant seem to find any info online about it to figure out how it works. Does anyone know about this method or can point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Is it related to. - https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barkley.
It seems the project is using a lagacy version of `react-hook-form`, whose version is `v5`.
You can find the api doc here:
https://react-hook-form.com/v5/api

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Frank3en, thank you so much. I imagined this was the issue but got lost somewhere along the line. Thank you for your help!